# Android Dynamic Feature

Tags: android, dynamic-feature-module

I am planning to implement a on-demand dynamic feature in one of my apps.
However, I wanted to know how long will this dynamic feature live on user's phone. Will it be auto deleted after x days of no usage, or will it live forever.

Also, what happens during upgrade of the mobile app. Does the dynamic feature module get auto-upgrade or previous version gets deleted and no new dynamic feature is installed until the user clicks again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help

1. Dynamic modules stays in the user device as long as the app exists. If you want to uninstall it you can us [deferredUninstalls](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/splitinstall/SplitInstallManager.html#deferredUninstall)
2. Google play will keep updating you app modules. Check [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/dynamic-delivery#manage_app_updates).